# App name appears as Xcode project when downloaded but is different on app store

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently released a new build of an app to the app store a bit ago. On iTunes connect I set the name which is displayed on the dashboard and in the app store, but when downloaded on a device, the name is the same as the original Xcode project on my computer. What is up with that? Is there something in the plist I need to change?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to change the bundle name in info.plist. It's default is **$(PRODUCT_NAME)**. And this product name is the one you put while creating the app in XCode at the beginning.

The App Store data is taken from the info you uploaded in iTunesConnect.

Also, if this varies widely then your app might got rejected. Check the guideline 3.4. About 2% of apps get rejected for this, [check here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/).

Answer (score 0):

The name that should be displayed on the device itself is defined on the plist in XCode in the `Bundle Display Name` field. The name that's displayed on the App Store is defined on iTunesConnect in the App Name field.

The two fields don't affect one another but they should be similar enough so that Apple's review team won't reject the app.